# Google Maps API V3 - Directions panel gets messed up when changing travel mode

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I'm building a Google map app where I need to give directions with multiple travel options, and I'm displaying the directions in a side panel.

But when I'm selecting a new directions request and passing it's results to the panel that's when things gets messed up, see the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/PLrkp/4/
here is how to reproduce it first select a direction using transit as the travel mode , then  change to bicycle and you'll see weird boxes in the section where you can choose alternative routes

**Note:** this only happens when 'provideRouteAlternatives' in the Directions request object is set to true, and only when there is actually more than one route, 
(it looks like that section is not being fully updated)

Here is my Code

```
    <div class="mapsection" >
      <form onsubmit="calcRoute();return false;">
          <select id="travelmode">
            <option value="DRIVING" selected="selected" data-shortMode="c">DRIVING</option>
            <option value="TRANSIT" data-shortMode="r" selected>TRANSIT</option>
            <option value="WALKING" data-shortMode="w">WALKING</option>
            <option value="BICYCLING" data-shortMode="b">BICYCLING</option>
          </select>
          <input type="text" id="start" value="Washington"/>
          <input type="text" id="end" value="New York"/>
          <button type="submit">GET DIRECTIONS</button>
      </form>
      <div id="map_canvas" style="width:100%; height:550px;float:left;"></div>
      <div id="directionsPanel" style="float:right;max-width:395px; overflow:scroll;height: 505px;overflow-x: hidden;"></div>
</div>
<script>
    //define one global Object
      var myMap = {}
      //init 
      function initialize(){
      //set up map options
        var mapOptions = {
          center: new google.maps.LatLng(40.75377,-73.990531),
          zoom: 4,
          mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
        };
        myMap.map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), mapOptions);
        myMap.directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();
        myMap.directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer();
        myMap.directionsDisplay.setMap(myMap.map);
        myMap.directionsDisplay.setPanel(document.getElementById("directionsPanel"));
      }//end init
      //directions
      var calcRoute = function() {
        var start = document.getElementById("start").value,
        end = document.getElementById("end").value,
        request = {
            origin:start,
            destination:end,
            durationInTraffic :true,
            transitOptions: {
            departureTime:  new Date()
          },
          provideRouteAlternatives : true,
          travelMode: document.getElementById("travelmode").value
        };
        myMap.directionsService.route(request, function(result, status) {
          if(status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
            myMap.directionsDisplay.setDirections(result);
          }else{
           alert("something went wrong!");
          }
        });

      }
      //script loader
      var loadScript = function() {
        var script = document.createElement("script");
        script.type = "text/javascript";
        script.src = "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_API_KEY_HERE&sensor=false&callback=initialize";
        document.body.appendChild(script);
      }
      window.onload = loadScript;
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue was fixed already, you can see it on the fiddle in the question